# NextJS Link isn't rendering an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using React + NextJS, and I'm trying to render a list of products, much like you'd see on a typical ecommerce category page. Each product is in a `p`, and that `p` should link to the appropriate detail page (so it should be surrounded by an anchor `a` tag).

Unfortunately, the links work but they don't render actual anchor tags. Can anyone explain what I'm missing?

**Scenario A: a normal text link (works as expected)**

---

> input:
>
> ```
> <Link href="wherever">word holmes</Link>
> ```
>
> output:
>
> ```
> <a href="wherever">word holmes</a>
> ```

**Scenario B: linking a block of whatever**

---

> input:
>
> ```
> <Link href="wherever">
>     <p>word holmes</p>
> </Link>
> ```
>
> output:
>
> ```
> <p>word holmes</p>
> ```
>
> desired output:
>
> ```
> <a href="wherever"><p>word holmes</p></a>
> ```

- where'd the `<a />` tag go??
- mousing over the block does not get a pointer cursor, but clicking it does send you to the `href` target

**Scenario C: adding my own `a` to the block of whatever**

---

> input:
>
> ```
> <Link href="wherever">
>     <a>
>         <p>word holmes</p>
>     </a>
> </Link>
> ```
>
> output:
>
> ```
> <a href="wherever"><p>word holmes</p></a>
> ```

- ok this works, but it feels hacky..
- why does this work? Is this the "right" way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/client/link.tsx the `a` tag is added automatically if the child is a string. Otherwise it just returns the child. So in your case the child is a `p` tag, so that's all that is returned. Seems like you could just wrap that in an `a` tag and that should work.

Comment: Thanks @Bafsky, I didn't think to check the source for the reason, good idea :)