# <Link> does not work as expected in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on creating a Next.js app and part of it requires me to create a dynamic route on click of a card component. However, after wrapping my Cards with the `<Link>` from Next.js, I am unable to navigate to the page as nothing happens on click. I tried adding an `<a>` tag under my `Link` and it worked. I am coming from react-router, and felt that just adding the `<Link>` should help navigate. Can someone explain the need for a `<a>` tag inside the Link component?

Below is the code that I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import OptionsDropdown from './components/OptionsDropdown';
import Card from './components/card';
import Link from 'next/link';

const Browse = () => {
  let filterByMenuEl = ['All items', 'Single items', 'Bundles'];
  let sortByMenuEl = ['Price: Low to High', 'Price: High to Low', 'Most Favorited'];
  let card1 = {
    name: 'Collectible 1',
    description: 'This is a description',
    price: '0.11',
    img: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Fviz0PWzUMQ98uvUZV8e_3y2R3D0nwk9q3jCQONoA2jh83vN2phkxEmLD3zpE1iiPOWNqh38rCqOC4agChgi704d0VGjgqwXrjiZ1Q=w600',
    list_date: 'here'
  }
  let card2 = {
    name: 'Collectible 2',
    description: 'This is a description',
    price: '0.12',
    img: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/8pQQRseehVjJ5PRZkXANawtaCooQfdTF9Ld3UvJVXxVaiixxM9x357NqLwFqindvDlKZ-XqbLytwzL-LxpiDPgJLIqOq5OHjhg5PAQ=w600',
    list_date: 'here'
  }
  let card3 = {
    name: 'Collectible 3',
    description: 'This is a description',
    price: '0.13',
    img: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a2w4nmFDYU1Z5kimGQtymbw7E-Jj8zrZRGiKmkmv03e9z5VJAFFqSIsvq39EjtlETwluC9hDGx6EpS5YOCVN6X6pTlAiOpuD5tYW=w600',
    list_date: 'here'
  }
  let card4 = {
    name: 'Collectible 4',
    description: 'This is a description',
    price: '0.14',
    img: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/P0FjJQ-9_YlBUtl6-pg5tgz1KUOqxgGRnB0u4v3C6YnY14cMWealXb5u3O2OI_Zr-YxMYaRs_b4TVrBTZzXF18_zhZ1WWPsBYj6xyg=w600',
    list_date: 'here'
  }
  let card5 = {
    name: 'Collectible 5',
    description: 'This is a description',
    price: '0.15',
    img: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/alrw4OsjldeYC5WpJCfneeui2F4lNDU0xYLp80LA9horlf7wufhRG_2ln5u72PLaNh9tF_3WqSXZoCFTgIC9GatkKPobLQ5zYJgrug=w600',
    list_date: 'here'
  }
  let card6 = {
    name: 'Collectible 6',
    description: 'This is a description',
    price: '0.16',
    img: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/lGp0y5VfF0j0gpe9OcY34inan58xkJuH6i6vCtCempSbUBMsF0cXexO_rFJNixIQP3n27M0L1waBS8oUI_JayefpzmB9Lw3q5oq6=w600',
    list_date: 'here'
  }

  let cards = [card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6];

  return(
    <div className='BrowsePage'>
      <div className='browse-options'>
        <div className='browse-results'>100,000 results</div>
        {/* <div className='options-spacer' /> */}
        <div className='browse-dropdowns'>
          <OptionsDropdown title='Filter by' menuEl={filterByMenuEl} />
          <OptionsDropdown title='Sort by' menuEl={sortByMenuEl} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='browse-main'>
        {cards.map((e, index) => {
          return (
          <Link href={"/browse/" + e.name} key = {e.name} passHref={true}>
              <Card
              key={index}
              name={e.name}
              description={e.description}
              price={e.price}
              img={e.img}
            />
          </Link>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div> 
  );
} 

export default Browse;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [NextJS Link isn't rendering an anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911391/nextjs-link-isnt-rendering-an-anchor-tag)? That's the expected behaviour, you have to wrap the child component with an `<a>` tag.

Comment: can you inspect the browser html and see what the href is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you use Link that imported from next and you want to put inside it a html element or jsx element not a text. then you have to wrap html element or jsx element with default anchor tag

```
<Link href={"/browse/" + e.name} key={e.name} passHref={true}>
    <a>
        <Card
            key={index}
            name={e.name}
            description={e.description}
            price={e.price}
            img={e.img}
        />
    </a>
</Link>
```

Comment: Wrapping an anchor tag is no longer required since NextJS 12.2: https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12-2

Answer (score 7):

> Can someone explain the need for a  tag inside the Link component?

You need `<a>` tag inside the Next.js Link Component if the children is not a string. Otherwise you do not need `<a>` tag. See: [NextJS Link isn't rendering an anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911391/nextjs-link-isnt-rendering-an-anchor-tag?noredirect=1&lq=1)
From : https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/client/link.tsx

Some thoughts on the `<a>` tag:

1. Content within each `<a>` should indicate the link's destination. If the href attribute is present, pressing the enter key while focused on the `<a>` element will activate it. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a
2. `<a>` is a tag that allows other elements within it to be right-clicked and has the options 'Open Link in New Tab', 'Copy Link Address', etc. (This is why I use this component.)

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in your slug routing.
Please check out Next documentation where is described route with dynamic segments.

```
function Posts({ posts }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <li key={post.id}>
          <Link href={`/blog/${encodeURIComponent(post.slug)}`}>
            <a>{post.title}</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Comment: make sure to add 'passHref` onto Link if you wrap it around an `a` tag

Comment: You don't need to use `passHref` if the child of the `Link` is an `<a>`. That should only be done when `Link` is used on a component that wraps the `<a>` tag itself. The above will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your issue is but here is how you can use dynamic next/link:

```js
{myArray.map((item) => (
 <NextLink href={`/something/${item.slug}`} passHref>
     <a href={`/something/${item.slug}`}>
         Dynamic link for {item.id}
      </a>
</NextLink>
))}
```

Quick how to:

1. Wrap NextLink around an `a` tag
2. Add `href` property on both
3. Add `passHref` property on NextLink to avoid 2 a tags rendering in html

Comment: There's no need to use `passHref` if the child is an `<a>` tag. You also don't need to (and shouldn't) set the `href` on the `<a>` tag.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-custom-component-that-wraps-an-a-tag you do need it

Comment: No, you don't need to use `passHref` if the child is an `<a>` tag (like in your example). You _do_ need to if the child is a component that wraps an `<a>`.

Answer (score -1):

Just add **rel="noopener"** as below ,
If it doesn't works then try adding **rel="noopener noreferrer"**

```
 <NextLink href={`/something/${item.slug}`} passHref>
     <a href={`/something/${item.slug}`} rel="noopener">
         Dynamic link for {item.id}
      </a>
</NextLink>
))}
```